# How to launch Playbook app from browser?

Tags: air, blackberry-playbook

I'm porting our Adobe Flex based virtual tour system to mobile, and can't seem to find any doumentation about custom url schemes on Playbook. iOS and Android both have the ability to process a custom url scheme and automatically open an app when the corresponding URL is launched in the browser. For example:

myapp://?data=lol

...would automatically launch the app and pass the {data: "lol"} parameter to it.

You can register the custom url schemes with parameters in the app.xml file used to compile it in Air, but it only seems to work for iOS and Android.

Our use case is that when a visitor opens a page containing our virtual tours, it should automatically open our app if it is installed, or ask them if they want to download it from the app store. Sorta the same way YouTube works on iOS.

How do you do this for the Playbook? Am I missing some vital documentation?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature for the PlayBook has not be provided yet by RIM, so you have no options to do this for now.  We're waiting for it, and expect it to be available some time this year... but that's speculation.  They are aware of the need for it.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. That's a HUGE oversight, hope they fix it soon. :(

Answer (score 0):

I've never tested this on Playbook, but i know Android got invoke-properties in -app.xml file where app://appid
or
app://appname

will call up your application, there should be something similar for Playbook as well.